# Unable to open port using boost asio

Tags: c++, windows, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to send simple signal on port COM2 using boost asio library. The problem is with this code. I get the error message saying: : **The system cannot find the file specified**.

```
io_service io;
serial_port port( io );
boost::system::error_code error;
if (!port.is_open()) {
    port.open("COM2", error);
    LOGI("Error: %s.", error.message().c_str());
}
```

What might be wrong? I have no device on this port and I don't really have any idea how all of this works. I had a task to send a simple 7-bit signal to COM2 port. But I am unable to go past opening port stage.
I'm on Windows 8.1 64-bit running VS2012.

Comment: Basic question: Your system definite HAS a COM2:?

Comment: My bad, using COM1 port seems to work. Thanks. Maybe you can also give me info on how to send 7 bits of data instead of 8? Currently I use this method: write( port, buffer( command, 1 ) ); and it seems, that the minimum value is one byte. On port settings I specify 7 for character_size. This time, please post your message as answer so I could mark it as correct answer ;)